# Is there a way to splice out elements of an array and return the spliced array in one line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

If I have an array `a = [1,2,3,4]` and I want to return it with the `3` removed, there are two ways I can do it:

```
let b = [...a] // or a.slice()
b.splice(2,1)
return b
```

or

```
return [...a.slice(0,2), ...a.slice(3,4)]
```

Advantage of the second is that it's one line. Disadvantage is that it's verbose. I thought of writing a helper function that contains the logic of the first approach, so that I'd be able to call it in one line elsewhere.

Is there an alternative? Something like `splice` but that returns that spliced array rather than mutating it and returning the spliced-out elements.

Comment: filter() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the indicies you want to remove, you can use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4];
const b = a.filter((_, i) => i !== 2);
console.log(b);
```

If you need to remove a range, you can just do something like `2 < i || i > 3`.

`.filter` makes a copy of the array, copying the values where the callback function evaluates truthy and ignores the values where the callback function evaluates falsy.